# Why do the purchases restore when I didn't buy any in app purchases?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I made a new sandbox test user to test the restore purchases button but when I press it and put my password or when I press cancel the levels still unlock. I don't get why this is happening. Can someone take a look at my code and tell me what Im doing wrong? Thanks!

```
   func RestorePurchases() {
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        println("Can't make purchases")

    }



    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
    println("transactions restored")


    var purchasedItemIDS = []
    for transaction in queue.transactions {



        var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction

        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {

        case "unlockLevelTwo":

            println("restoreleveltwo")
            NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel2")
            unlockLevelTwoPlease()

        case "unlockLevelThree":
            println("restorelevelthree")
            NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel3")
            unlockLevelThreePlease()

        default:
            println("IAP not setup")
                let alert = UIAlertView()
                alert.title = "Oops"
                alert.message = "There are no purchases to restore, please buy one"
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
                alert.show()


        }

    }

}

//EDITED MORE CODE....

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");




    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        var trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        println(trans.error)


        switch trans.transactionState {



            case .Purchased:
                let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID {

            case "unlockLevelTwo":
                    println("unlocksleveltwo")

                NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel2")

                unlockLevelTwoPlease()
            case "unlockLevelThree":
                println("unlocklevelthree")
                NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel3")
                unlockLevelThreePlease()
            default:
                println("")
                }

                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;
            case .Failed:
                println("Purchased Failed");
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;
        case .Restored:
            let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID {
        case "unlockLevelTwo":
            println("unlocksleveltwo")

            NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel2")

            unlockLevelTwoPlease()
        case "unlockLevelThree":
            println("unlocklevelthree")
            NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel3")
            unlockLevelThreePlease()
        default:
            println("")
        }

            default:
                println("default")
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're in the wrong method.

From Apple documentation, `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` tells the observer that the payment queue has finished sending restore transactions. This method is called after all restorable transactions have been processed by the payment queue. Your application is nos required to do anything in this method.

I suppose you've implemented `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions`. You should examine the transactionState `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` and unlock your levels there.

Comment: So I don't need paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished, I could just use the .Restored?

Comment: It's not mandatory for you to do anything in paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished. But you should definitely implement paymentQueue:updatedTransactions for transactionState SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored. Give it a try and let me know!

Comment: I have a question...I have two seperate in app purchases could I just put it in the .Restored together because for the .Purchased I added a switch statement?

Comment: What do you mean by .Restored and .Purchased?

Comment: Ill post the code for the updatedTransactions in the op so you get what im saying.

Comment: I added the code in the op can you take a look at it? Thanks!

Comment: No, no! You don't call restoreCompletedTransactions there! The method restoreCompletedTransactions starts the whole restoration process: you should call it when the user wants to restore the products (for example, after pressing a button). Inside paymentQueue:updatedTransactions, in the SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored state, you should unlock the levels as you do when the user buy those levels for the first time.

Comment: In the SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored state do I have to put the products in a case like I did in the .Purchased state?

Comment: Yes, because the transaction arrived as a restoration (like a purchase but without paying for it).

Comment: switch prodID {

        case "unlockLevelTwo":

            println("restoreleveltwo")
            NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel2")
            unlockLevelTwoPlease()

        case "unlockLevelThree":
            println("restorelevelthree")
            NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Leavel3")
            unlockLevelThreePlease()

Comment: I get an error saying this fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value for this line: 
              let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80006/discussion-between-leandro-and-coding22).